# How can I use TextFormatFlags as property for an inherited control?

Tags: vb.net

I have create a custom `OwnerDraw` inherited `ToolTip` control into a `Class` and I have also add some **custom properties**. My `TextRenderer` looks like this:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.ToolTipText, Me.Font, e.Bounds,
                      Me.ForeColor, Me.BackColor,
                      TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)
```

I want to make `TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter` and `TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter` comes from a custom property, so I did this:

```
Private _AlignVertical As TextFormatFlags
<Category("Custom Properties")> <DisplayName("Align Vertical")> <Description("ToolTip's text vertical align.")>
Public Property AlignVertical As TextFormatFlags
    Get
        Return _AlignVertical
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As TextFormatFlags)
        _AlignVertical = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private _AlignHorizontal As TextFormatFlags
<Category("Custom Properties")> <DisplayName("Align Horizontal")> <Description("ToolTip's text horizontal align.")>
Public Property AlignHorizontal As TextFormatFlags
    Get
        Return _AlignHorizontal
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As TextFormatFlags)
        _AlignHorizontal = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Then I changed `TextRenderer` to this:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.ToolTipText, Me.Font, e.Bounds,
                      Me.ForeColor, Me.BackColor, 
                      Me.AlignHorizontal Or Me.AlignVertical)
```

And I have also add this into my `Public Sub New()`:

```
Me.AlignHorizontal = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter
Me.AlignVertical = TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter
```

My problem is, when I go to properties panel, into `AlignHorizontal` and `AlignVertical` I see `Left, Default, Top, HorizontalCenter` and `Left, Default, Top, VerticalCenter` as values and not `HorizontalCenter` and `VerticalCenter` as I think they should be. Also, in my `Form`s `Designer` I get error because those values looks like this:

```
Me.Form_CustomToolTip.AlignHorizontal = System.Windows.Forms.TextFormatFlags.Left, Default, Top, HorizontalCenter
Me.Form_CustomToolTip.AlignVertical = System.Windows.Forms.TextFormatFlags.Left, Default, Top, VerticalCenter
```

Αny kind of guidance would be really appreciated!!!

Comment: It is not the kind of enum type that works well in the designer.  It acts as a bitmask, not a list of values.  Do this the friendly and logical way, change these property types to Boolean.  And write a little helper method that returns TextFormatFlags, using these properties to calculate the value.  You also need to call Me.Invalidate() in their property setters so the text is redrawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, I made it work with this simple way below. If someone have something better or more proper...

First I replaced `TextFormatFlags` properties with a `ContentAlignment`:

```
Private _TextAlign As ContentAlignment
<Category("Custom Properties")> <DisplayName("Text Align")> <Description("The alignment of text in the ToolTip.")>
Public Property TextAlign As ContentAlignment
    Get
        Return _TextAlign
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As ContentAlignment)
        _TextAlign = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

And then I added an `IF` statement before my `TextRenderer` which "converts" values from `TextFormatFlags` to `ContentAlignment`:

```
Dim _Flags As TextFormatFlags
If Me.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter Then
    _Flags = TextFormatFlags.Bottom Or TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter
ElseIf Me.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomLeft Then
    _Flags = TextFormatFlags.Bottom Or TextFormatFlags.Left
ElseIf Me.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomRight Then
    _Flags = TextFormatFlags.Bottom Or TextFormatFlags.Right
ElseIf Me.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter Then
    _Flags = TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter
ElseIf Me.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft Then
    _Flags = TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.Left
ElseIf Me.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight Then
    _Flags = TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.Right
ElseIf Me.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter Then
    _Flags = TextFormatFlags.Top Or TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter
ElseIf Me.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft Then
    _Flags = TextFormatFlags.Top Or TextFormatFlags.Left
ElseIf Me.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopRight Then
    _Flags = TextFormatFlags.Top Or TextFormatFlags.Right
End If
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.ToolTipText, Me.Font, e.Bounds, Me.ForeColor, Me.BackColor, _Flags)
e.Graphics.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

For C# developers coming here and appreciating Simonetos The Greek's answer, like me, here is a C# translation of the flags assignation:

```
switch (TextAlign)
{
    case ContentAlignment.BottomCenter:
        return TextFormatFlags.Bottom | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter;
    case ContentAlignment.BottomLeft:
        return TextFormatFlags.Bottom | TextFormatFlags.Left;
    case ContentAlignment.BottomRight:
        return TextFormatFlags.Bottom | TextFormatFlags.Right;
    case ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
        return TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter;
    case ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft:
        return TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Left;
    case ContentAlignment.MiddleRight:
        return TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Right;
    case ContentAlignment.TopCenter:
        return TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter;
    case ContentAlignment.TopLeft:
        return TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.Left;
    case ContentAlignment.TopRight:
        return TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.Right;
    default:
        return TextFormatFlags.Default;
}
```